# JavaScript: Clear search-field when enter with mouse?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, textbox

I have a textfield () in my homepage for a searchstring.
Normaly I have a text like "enter here to searach..." in it.

Now I will clear the box from the text when a user click into it.

How to solve?
JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by using the `placeholder` attribute in HTML. Example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="e.g. John Doe">
```

For browsers who don’t support this attribute natively, you could use JavaScript.

If you’re using jQuery, you could consider using [my placeholder plugin for jQuery](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin), which is the most robust solution I’ve seen. Here’s a demo page: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder

Answer (score 2):

create a JavaScript file or use a current one then write in it:

```
Function function_name()
{

    document.getEelementByName("Control_Name").setAttribute("Value", '');
}
```

---

then in the page head:

```
<script id="js1" type="text/javascript" src="dir/file_name.js"></script>
```

The Control Tag become:

```
<input type="text" name="Control_Name" onClick="return js1/function_name();" />
```

Comment: This answer has four errors: `return js1/function_name();`, 'Function' should be lower case, `getEelementByName` should be `getElementsByName` and that return an array Lastly, this doesn't restore the value after the user leaves the field if they haven't typed anything.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need javascript to achieve this. You could subscribe for the `onclick` event and when this event is triggered set the text to empty and then unsubscribe from the onclick event to avoid clearing the text every time a user clicks:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo');
foo.onfocus = function() {
    foo.value = '';
    foo.onfocus = null;
};
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L9W9L/1/).

And if you are using jquery there is a really nice [watermark plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) which allows you to do this.

Comment: You don’t need JavaScript to achieve this — only for older browsers. Just use `@placeholder` in the HTML. See my answer for more information.

Comment: @Kovu, I've updated my answer to include an example. Also look at @Mathias Bynens's answer which offers a very nice HTML5 solution which doesn't require javascript for browsers that support it (normally all modern browsers).

Comment: This is a dangerous solution, because it deletes everything, and not just the placeholder text.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing an `onfocus` Javascript handler; that will be triggered whether you’ve clicked it or tabbed into it.

```
<input type="text" name="..." value="" onfocus="this.value = '';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onfocus and onblur javascript methods

```
<input type="text" name="searchinput" onblur="this.value='enter here to search...';" onfocus="this.value = '';" />
```